# not letting me paint on the face of my character

Tags: texture-painting

I wanted to make a Blender gift for my friend, but whenever I try to paint on the face or base area, it darkens and only lets me paint on the ears.

I have tried things like disabling and enabling backface culling and checked my shaders but nothing has worked. Please help me!

[image]

Comment: hello, maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: okay i did [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=RlsqnwEV" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/RlsqnwEV/)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems here: You haven't unwrapped the body, and you have overlapping faces. So first, apply the scale in *Object* mode, go in *Edit* mode, select all and press <kbd>M</kbd> to *Merge by Distance* with a distance of 0.001 in the *Operator* box. Then unwrap with the *Smart UV Project* mode (if you only plan to paint in the 3D view), give a bit of *Island Margin* if you want to avoid bleeding painting.

Comment: it kind of work ? but now i have these little bits of random squares all over the place covering most of it's head

Comment: it works fine for me, could you please share your new file?

Comment: here: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=Rrovk69z" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/Rrovk69z/)

Comment: in the new file you share you haven't followed all the steps I describe, please follow all the steps

Comment: oh it works fine now, i'm sorry about earlier. thank you !!